# How does rpy2 handles warnings in R?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

```
In [1]: import rpy2

In [2]: import rpy2.robjects as robjects

In [3]: robjects.r['warning']("hello")
Out[3]: 
<StrVector - Python:0x7f115a1e34d0 / R:0x1243d18>
['hello']
```

It seems warning messages are directly transformed to string, which is correct.

But where is the waring?

While in R, it would print

```
Warning message:
hello
```

in red.

So how can I know if a function has triggered any warnings?

Comment: can you catch it in R? the ```test_that``` has a ```expect_warning``` function that returns a boolean

Comment: or a function ```givesWarning=function(x){
  return(tryCatch(expr={x;F},warning=function(w)return(T)))
}```